# Intellij Idea - Define custom and different Gradle User Home by Project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am working with `ideaIC-2020.2.3`

I am able two open two windows to *open* two different projects for each window respectively. These projects are based on Gradle, for example

- Spring Framework
- Spring Integration

About `settings` I am able to define the `gradle user home` location, but it is common for all the projects. I want to know (if is possible - by the IDE itself or through a special plugin) define for each Project a custom and isolated (or different) *gradle user home* location. I tried for each project do right clic and `Open Module Settings` and does not exist something to accomplish this goal.

**Observation**: in STS/Eclipse - for Maven is possible for example that for each workspace import a custom and different `settings.xml` file indicating a specific and different repository.

Comment: Why do you need to set different Gradle home?

Comment: Normally for Maven, about the local repository when the bandwidth goes wrong, the repository is corrupted, therefore must be deleted and download all again. It never happens with Gradle, but I use isolated repositories (for Maven and Gradle) to keep all isolated in case some is corrupted and delete the repository if some project is discarded.

Comment: My request is about mostly about the `gradle user home`. If it can be applied for `gradle home` would be nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Please vote for [IDEA-163506](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163506).

Comment: I am going to give my vote in the link shared (I must create an account first). I assume the same problem exists for Maven too.